# How can I make an local notification after app go to background a day in Android

Tags: android, notifications

I want develop a remind return feature for my Android app. I want after a day from when user not use app, I will show a local notification, remind user that "We have more new content, touch here to read new content".
But I don't know how to code.

- I don't know how to detect app is begin in to background (onPause can fire on app enter background, but also when app change activity).
- How can I fire notification when app in background. I have this function to show notifcation, but it show after I call it. How can I delay it a day.

showNotification()

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.down_icon, getString(R.string.press_back_again_if_you_want_to_exit_app), System.currentTimeMillis());

Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, this.getString(R.string.press_back_again_if_you_want_to_exit_app),
        this.getString(R.string.press_back_again_if_you_want_to_exit_app), pendingIntent);
notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
```

I develop feature very easy in iOS, but in Android, I don't know how to do.

Comment: hello huy : have you find the solution for this one? I still get stuck on this for Android side.

Comment: I haven't found a good solution yet

Answer (score 2):

to achieve your requirement follow the below steps.

step1- When your app starts start a background service. In the service check the top most activity every time interval

step2-In service when the top most activity not belongs to your app then schedule the alarm to fire after 24 hrs and destroy the service.

Answer (score 1):

To send a notification from the background, you will use a Service or a BroadcastReceiver, not an Activity. I think the BroadcastReceiver will best suit your necessity: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

To schedule the execution, use the AlarmManager. You can set the alarm during the other Activity lifecycle methods: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Answer (score -1):

For that you need to write service which check "activity state is in OnPause() state?" in every time interval. and after that you can fire notification whatever you want.
thank you.

Comment: Is it take more CPU? It is a simple task, so I don't want it take more system resource. I don't want use services because user may be not feel pleased